# Display external wwb page inside Flash application

Tags: flash

Basically a short question, but really couldn't find a answer.

Is it possible to load and display an external website inside a Flash application? If so, how can thos be done?

Comment: It is not possible to display an external website in a Flash Application.  Flash's support for displaying HTML content is basic html markup in TextFields by setting the `htmlText` property.

Comment: Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText